# Returning the wrong type - cast?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-web-api

In a Web API 2 project, i am trying to get all the coordinates belonging to a single item (can be anywhere from 1 to 1000s) and calculating the centerpoint.
The function to calculate the centerpoint, works, as expected.

But the below controller fails, with the error: `Cannot implicitly convert SYstem.Linq.IQueryable<System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinates> to System.Linq.IQueryable<ItemDTO>`. in the line `return items.AsQueryable();`

How can i get it to return as a `ItemDTO`?

Model

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Location> Locations { get; set; }
}

public class ItemDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<GeoCoordinate> Coordinates { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string cX { get; set; }
    public string cY { get; set; }
    public virtual Item Item { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public IQueryable<ItemDTO> GetList()
{
    var sourceItems = db.Items.Include(x => x.Locations).ToList(); 

    var items = sourceItems.Select(item => new ItemDTO()
        {
            Id = item.Id,
            Title = item.Title
            Coordinates = item.Locations
                .Select(itemLocation => new GeoCoordinate()
                {
                    Latitude = Double.Parse(itemLocation.cX, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                    Longitude = Double.Parse(itemLocation.cY, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                })
        })
        .AsEnumerable()
        .Select(fetchedItem => GetCentralGeoCoordinate(fetchedItem.Coordinates));

    return items.AsQueryable();
}
```

Method

```
public static GeoCoordinate GetCentralGeoCoordinate(IEnumerable<GeoCoordinate> geoCoordinates)
    {
        if (geoCoordinates.Count() == 1)
        {
            return geoCoordinates.Single();
        }

        double x = 0;
        double y = 0;
        double z = 0;

        foreach (var geoCoordinate in geoCoordinates)
        {
            var latitude = geoCoordinate.Latitude * Math.PI / 180;
            var longitude = geoCoordinate.Longitude * Math.PI / 180;

            x += Math.Cos(latitude) * Math.Cos(longitude);
            y += Math.Cos(latitude) * Math.Sin(longitude);
            z += Math.Sin(latitude);
        }

        var total = geoCoordinates.Count();

        x = x / total;
        y = y / total;
        z = z / total;

        var centralLongitude = Math.Atan2(y, x);
        var centralSquareRoot = Math.Sqrt(x * x + y * y);
        var centralLatitude = Math.Atan2(z, centralSquareRoot);

        return new GeoCoordinate(centralLatitude * 180 / Math.PI, centralLongitude * 180 / Math.PI);
    }
```

Comment: your error is because of this line :`.Select(fetchedItem => GetCentralGeoCoordinate(fetchedItem.Coordinates));` At the end of your Query you tried to select `GeoCoordinate ` with your `Select` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the signature, The method `IQueryable<ItemDTO> GetList()` should return a value of type `IQueryable<ItemDTO>`, the method `GetCentralGeoCoordinate` should return a value of type `GeoCoordinate`.

Now take a look into the `GetList()` method, in this: the query selects

```
.Select(fetchedItem => GetCentralGeoCoordinate(fetchedItem.Coordinates));
```

which means each item in the selected code is of type `GeoCoordinate` and hence `items.AsQueryable()` will give you `IQueryable<GeoCoordinate>`. which is not equivalent or convertible to `IQueryable<ItemDTO>` and that causes the issues.

> Either you have to change the signature of `GetList` to
>   `IQueryable<GeoCoordinate>` or need to create a method to get the
>   `IQueryable<ItemDTO>` from `fetchedItem` to solve the issue.

You can make a try with the following code:

```
public IQueryable<ItemDTO> GetList()
{
    var sourceItems = db.Items.Include(x => x.Locations).ToList(); 
    var items = sourceItems.Select(item => new ItemDTO()
        {
            Id = item.Id,
            Title = item.Title
            Coordinates = GetCentralGeoCoordinate(
                          item.Locations
                              .Select(itemLocation => new GeoCoordinate()
                               {
                                  Latitude = Double.Parse(itemLocation.cX, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                                  Longitude = Double.Parse(itemLocation.cY, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                               })
                          });       

    return items.AsQueryable();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply :-) How could a solution look? Or, could i be using the GetCentralGeoCoordinate function elsewhere? I want the output to be the ItemDTO with all the values that belongs to that, along with the value that GetCentralGeoCoordinate  returns

Comment: @brother why don't you  use `GetCentralGeoCoordinate` in this line `Coordinates = item.Locations`

Comment: @brother: I have made some updates in the answer, please review them and let me know\

Comment: @un-lucky I think its getting close! :-) I am now getting an error in the GetCentralGeoCoordinate(...) saying: Cannot convert from System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinate> to System.Collections.Generic.IList<System.Device.Location.GetCoordinate>. Adding a ToList() after the select(), gives me the error Cannot implicitly convert type System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinate to IList<..>

Comment: Nevermind - figured it out. Had to change my Coordinates definition to GeoCoordinate instead og a IList - of course :-) Thank you!